# tensorflow pip install on windows > error " no perl script found in input"

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip, installation

im trying to install tensorflow on my computer. I have windows 10. Im doing CPU only pip install. When i paste this (pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl) command into my command prompt i get error message that says "no perl script found in input". What is the problem? is it referring to Perl programming language or something else? how is perl related to any of this? Thanks!!!

Comment: solved!!! this article explains it >>> https://www.penwatch.net/cms/pip_conflict/

Answer (score 0):

what python version installed in your environment ?

if it's 3.6 you can simply replace the -cp35-cp35m- become -cp36-cp36m-

I hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the "No Perl script found in input" error myself, in a different situation (as is, not trying to use pip).

The original poster has supplied a comment that answers the question he asked; he had two "pip"s in his path and the wrong one was before the right one. He either had to change the order of his path or supply a full pathname.

This helped me solve my problem; I was using the command line lwp-download to download a file and suddenly got this error. Running lwp-download.bat solved my problem.

If you experience the "No Perl script found in input" error, try running "where" and then your command; in my example "where lwp-download". If you have more than one file in your path with that name, try to be specific. In my case, add the ".bat"